# Displaying join table row in view (has_many through association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

The thing is: I'm doing a basic diet planner which has meals, ingredients and quantities.
When a user make a meal, he select the ingredients and set the quantity of it.
All I want is to display in the meal index page rows with the ingredients and its quantities.

```
<% meal.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
          <% ingredient.quantities.each do |q| %>
            <td><%= q.quant %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td><%= ingredient.unit %></td>
          <td><%= ingredient.carb %></td>
          <td><%= ingredient.prot %></td>
          <td><%= ingredient.fat %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

This is showing all quantities associated with the selected ingredient. I'm not posting models because I think it's too obvious.
Thanks

**EDIT**

db/schema.rb

```
  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "unit"
    t.float    "carb"
    t.float    "prot"
    t.float    "fat"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "quantities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float   "quant"
    t.integer "ingredient_id"
    t.integer "meal_id"
  end
```

views/meals/index.html.erb

```
<% @meals.each do |meal| %>
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2><%= meal.name %></h2>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Show', meal %>
            </li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meal_path(meal) %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to '', meal, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "fa fa-close" %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">

      <table class="table table-striped">

        <tbody>
          <% meal.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
              <% ingredient.quantities.each do |q| %>
                <td><%= q.quant %></td>
              <% end %>
              <td><%= ingredient.unit %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.carb %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.prot %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.fat %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Meal', new_meal_path %>
```

[image]
The highlighted numbers are quantities from banana ingredient. 
However, for the meal it's associated I want only "123".
I guess it's a problem of queries and I don't find out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post examples of row data and outputs?  It's difficult to tell what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I've added more code and explained a little further. If you need something else, just tell me :) thanks

Comment: So that I understand what you're asking, you just want that line to show `Banana     123` and no other values?

Comment: Exactly! This quantity is a param for the join table (igredient_id, meal_id and quant). So I want to display this quantity based on the ids it's related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Listing Meals</h1>
<% @meals.each do |meal| %>
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2><%= meal.name %></h2>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Show', meal %>
            </li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meal_path(meal) %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to '', meal, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "fa fa-close" %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">

      <table class="table table-striped">

        <tbody>
          <% meal.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
<!-- FILTERED INGREDIENT QUANTITY ACCORDING TO MEAL ID -->
              <td><%= ingredient.quantities.find_by(meal_id: meal.id).quant %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.unit %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.carb %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.prot %></td>
              <td><%= ingredient.fat %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Meal', new_meal_path %>
```

I just don't know if it's the best solution, but worked for me!

Comment: You should already be filtered by `meal` at that point.  3 lines above that shows `meal.ingredients.each`, which makes the query related only to the meal.  You shouldn't have to do a separate `find_by(meal_id)` within that, unless there's something really wrong with your relationships and/or your data.

Comment: Note that it's also very bad form to embed a database query in your view.  You want your queries in the controller, and only the display logic in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for:

```
<% meal.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
    <td><%= ingredient.quantities.first.quant %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This will display the ingredient name and the first quantity for the ingredient.  It will not display any additional quantities for the ingredient, not the carb, protein, or fat amounts.

Comment: you pluralized ingredients intentionally? 
I didn't find out where this answear can be used. I edited my post so you can understand better my point. Thanks again

Comment: I have updated the answer with what I think you're asking for.

Comment: Yes but it's not always the first, imagine an Excel sheet where you make yourself a diet. The difference is I'm using many to many relation because I want the user to use an ingredient that already exists, and I'm dealing with the quantity as a join table.

Comment: So how do you tell which quantity you want to use for the ingredient *banana*, if there are 2 quantities available in the recipe?  With your schema, that's completely possible.  Do you add them together and present one quantity for that ingredient, or do you display the first amount.  Based on your example, I displayed the first quantity, even though it appeared that there might be 2 quantities (123.0 and 1.0) for *banana*.  I can change it to add them together, if that's what you want.  That's ONLY adding quantities for the exact same ingredient - quantities for *salt* don't add to *banana*.

Comment: if you look at how Rails describes the relationship, `ingredient` (singular) can have `quantities` (plural).  This means that one recipe can have one ingredient with multiple quantities.  When you read the code, you can see `ingredient.quantities`, which isn't obvious what needs to be done.  It requires you to tell me how to handle multiple quantities of the same ingredient.

Comment: That's plural because 1 ingredient id may have many quantities associated to different meals, right? I want to store a meal id, then store a ingredient id and display the only join table possible with the 'quant' argument. The way I'm doing to achieve that is wrong ?

Comment: What my answer says is that the first quantity of each ingredient for the meal is to be shown.  From everything that you've shared, this looks correct, **unless** it's possible to have an ingredient included more than one time for a meal.  Is that possible in your application?  If not, this should be your answer.